# Street-view Image not rendering in CartoDB infoWindow

Tags: carto, google-street-view

Following instructions on [Infowindows with Google Street View Images](http://blog.cartodb.com/a-picture-is-worth-1-000-attributes-infowindows-with/), I'm trying to add this feature to a visualization

Instead of an image, I'm simply getting the link to the image via the SQL query as text:

[image]

Wondering if I've done anything wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used this feature of CartoDB, but it looks like you need to select "Image Header" as the infowindow design template. Have you done that?

Failing that, just code the infowindow in raw HTML, using an `<img>` tag.